# Dynamic sender profile with AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My Client is sending to 40 different countries a unique, localized and highly personalized email. They want to have a different sender profile depending on the contact country code, including a different reply email address. Is that possible ? What should be the best way to accomplish this?

If this is not possible, can we use one unique sender profile, and use AMPscript in order to personalize sender name, sender email address, AND reply email address ?

Comment: Be careful when adding Profile Attributes, for these show up in Profile Center for subscribers to see! Make sure to create them as "hidden" if only using for "hacky" purposes :)

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to the "personalization" method described above, if you have the business rule "ENHANCED SENDER PROFILE" (you may need to contact support to have this enabled) turned on you can use AMPscript to pull back information from a DE.
e.g. for from name

```
%%[ VAR @fromName 
SET @fromName = Lookup("MySendProfilesDE","FROM_NAME", "SendProfileField", SENDABLE_DE_FIELD_TO_DRIVE_PROFILE) 
IF EMPTY (@fromName) THEN 
    SET @fromName = 'MyDefaultFromName' 
ENDIF ]%% 
%%=v(@fromName)=%%
```

Where:

**MySendProfileDE** is a DE used for the lookup

**FROM_NAME** is the field in the above DE that you want to be used

**SendProfileField** is the field in above DE you are matching on

**SENDABLE_DE_FIELD_TO_DRIVE_PROFILE** is a value from your sendable DE that is used for the lookup.  As was mentioned previously I think any field that you use for this will need to appear as a profile attribute (even though a DE is used for sending)

Comment: How do I know if the ENHANCED SENDER PROFILE is enabled in my account?

Comment: @fromero  if you put some ampscript into the `From Email` field, then tab out of the input field (= click somewhere else, other than on a link or button), the page will reload to "validate" the email you just inserted, and, if you have it enabled, show you a checkbox and a secondary input field for a fallback email address for you to insert in case the ampscript returns something bad or an email address thats not validated.

same info in the docs: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sender_profile.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

I have done this very thing.  Here is what I did:

1. I added a Profile Attribute called FromName and FromEmail to the account.  You need to do this in order to get the AMPscript to validate, even though you're never going to use them directly (its "hacktastic").
2. In the sendable DataExtension you're going to use for your send (I'm assuming you're sending to a DE based on the complexity you're describing) ... add 2 nullable columns called FromName and FromEmail.
3. Create a Sender Profile.  In the From Name section put %%FromName%%, in the From Email section put %%FromEmail%%.
4. Create a User Initiated send to use that profile with your email.
5. Create a Query activity to do the logic to populate the FromName and FromEmail DE columns at send time.
6. Create an automation to run the query, then run the UIsend.

This may be overkill for what you are trying to do, but at least, you have an answer that works!

Comment: When I tried to put %%FromEmail%% under From Email section I get a validation error.
'" A problem occurred updating your sender profile. Please contact Customer Service for additional information. ...........The format of the FromAddress address is not valid.." I need to dynamically update From email address. I am using .NET code to send email through exactTarget. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you make sure to add the profile attribute?

Comment: Timothy, Yes I added the profile attribute.

Comment: @Timothy This can be used for Trigger Send?

Comment: @Timothy what's the profile attribute used for? I don't really understand the hack...

Comment: Finally, I'm back on StackEx.  The profile attribute is used for lists.  At the time of this original post, some of the list functionality was being used during a data extension send.