# How to create a Dynamic Reply-to address in Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I cannot get this dynamic sender profile to populate a *dynamic Reply-to email address* using a field from a non-sendable data extension (something that should be easy but its turning out to be really difficult). I understand that the Sender Profile is evaluated before the email, so the ampscript from the email cannot be used.

---

Therefor, I have attempted to create a content block and put this ampscript in it:

%%[

Set @language_email = language_code 
Set @Replyto_table = "Ashley_Reply_To"
Set @replyto_match = "fromReply"
Set @replyto_translated = Lookup(@Replyto_table, "language_code_reply", @replyto_match, @language_email)

]%%

%%=v(@replyto_translated)=%%

---

Then I retrieve the content block using this script in the Sender Profile:

### %%=ContentBlockByName("Ashley_Replyto_Contentblock")=%%

This is not working and I am not sure what to do! Help!!
[image]

Comment: check this
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/dynamic-sender-profile-with-ampscript?rq=1

Comment: @A.Malone what error you getting for me its working   this one %%=ContentBlockByName("Ashley_Replyto_Contentblock")=%%
 where did you use this one ?

Comment: Hi @pkharries. The email is just not sending through at all. They all have status "Cancelled" in the send log

Comment: iam asking where did you use this one %%=ContentBlockByName("Ashley_Replyto_Contentblock")=%%

Comment: @pkharries oops sorry didnt answer your other Q. I am using it in the Sender Profile. Use custom settings below --> Use specified information --> Address(required)

Comment: any error you getting?

Comment: @pkharries I am not sure how to check for errors on while the send failed. All it says is "Cancelled" in the My tracking area

Comment: sender profile  screen share here

Comment: @A.Malone this sender profile is saving ?

Comment: Have you tried putting the script into the field directly? Also we found when using dynamic sender script in the from field that pulling subscriber information from the sending data extension didn't work out. We had to use the Subscriberkey in the all subscriber list for the lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [ContentBlockbyName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyname.htm) you should provide full path to your content block, for example:

```
%%=ContentBlockbyName('Content Builder\Scripts\Ashley_Replyto_Contentblock') =%%
```

You can copy location in content builder:

[image] 
[image]

P.S. I would suggest to use ContentBlockbyId or ContentBlockbyKey in case someone will change location or rename your block.

Updated note: Make sure you save this content block as a **Code Snippet**!!! Otherwise you will have problems:)

Comment: Its a miracle!!!!!!! It finally works!!! And the greatest part is that Salesforce Help told me it isnt possible to have this information in a section data extension:) High five to us

Comment: Use the feedback function in your support case and tell them that there is a solution the support didnt know about. It will increase their effectivity.

Comment: @A.Malone actually i am TA at Salesforce, could you give me your case number?