# Dynamic From Address & From Name

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, dataextensions

I am trying to pull the FromAddress and FromName, from a data extension but am not having much luck.

I have setup a sender profile that looks like this:

```
From Name: %%=v(@fromName)=%%
From Address: %%=v(@fromAddress)=%%
```

---

My Data Extension Looks like this:

```
brandcode
fromname
fromaddress
```

---

The Ampscript in my email template looks like this:

```
Var @fromname, @fromaddress, @brandcode, @row, @rows, @rowcount

Set @brandcode = AttributeValue("Brandcode")

Set @rows = LookupRows("senderinfo", "brandcode", @brandcode)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    set @row = row(@rows,1) 
    set @fromname = field(@row,"fromname")
    set @fromaddress = field(@row,"fromaddress")


ENDIF
```

---

What I am trying to do is this.

```
IF Brandcode = AA Then use the fromname and from address for AA

IF Brandcode = BB then use the fromname and from address for BB
```

My code validates but it uses the "default" sender info and is not using the lookup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic sender profile with AmpScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/dynamic-sender-profile-with-ampscript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you cannot pull the From Name / From Address from inside of the email body.

The order of processing puts the From Name/Address ahead of the HTML Body.  Meaning those variables are empty until after they have been declared.

So at this point you have 3 options:

1. Put the full AMPScript into each item: (This can get messy and hard to edit)

From Name:

```
%%[ Var @fromname, @fromaddress, @brandcode, @row, @rows, @rowcount

Set @brandcode = AttributeValue("Brandcode")

Set @rows = LookupRows("senderinfo", "brandcode", @brandcode)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    set @row = row(@rows,1) 
    set @fromname = field(@row,"fromname")   

ENDIF ]%% %%=v(@fromname)=%%
```

2. Put the entire script into a content block **(My recommendation)**

Content Block:

```
Var @fromname, @fromaddress, @brandcode, @row, @rows, @rowcount

Set @brandcode = AttributeValue("Brandcode")

Set @rows = LookupRows("senderinfo", "brandcode", @brandcode)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    set @row = row(@rows,1) 
    set @fromname = field(@row,"fromname")
    set @fromaddress = field(@row,"fromaddress")


ENDIF
```

From Name:  `%%[ContentBlockByID("yourID")]%% %%=v(@fromname)=%%`

3. You can just pull directly from the field inside the sendable DE. (I would recommend putting a 'default' value on both of these fields)

From Name: `%%fromname%%`

Anything you put in the email html will not affect the from name or address - so I believe the above are your only options.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and answer. We currently use option 3 but am looking to change that. Will trial 1 and 2. Prob just go with 1.

Answer (score -1):

If the information you are trying to pull is within the sendable DE, I would recommend option 3 of @Gortonington's answer.

You can also do it this way:

```
var @fromName
set @fromName = [fromname]
```

Comment: Hello Mayorga,welcome to the SFSE community. I personally disagree with your answer. because your ampscript snippets does not contain any output. Furthermore it does not make sense to create a variable, set this variable and then do nothing with it. You can achieve the same with %%fromname%% if this would be inside your dataextension. Remember that the question is about pulling these fields into the sender profile fromname and fromemail and not into the email body. I personally highly disagree to chose the third option because you have duplicate data all over the place. Recommending the second