# Marketing cloud journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am running a journey and sending an email to four types of users. ( language based) 
I want to send this email to all other kinds of users from the different send classification.
Explanation - 
I am using the single email, and the content of the email is dynamic it changes based on the user language and now want to send the same email to different users from different sender profile Through journey.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to use [Dynamic Sender Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_dynamic_sender_profile.htm&type=5) to have different sender profiles based on the dynamic attributes of the email recipient.

You'll need to enable "ENHANCED SENDER PROFILE" through support and use AMPscript in the Sender Profile.

Here is a relevant question on [Dynamic Sender Profiles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/dynamic-sender-profile-with-ampscript).